# Mysqli connects to totaly different IP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I try to connect to my server (ip 5.39.6*.**) by mysqli_connect oop version (tested procedual version too) and it always gives me this error message:

Access denied for user '****'@'62.214.6*.***' (using password: YES)

My problem is the IP in the error message totaly doesnt match the IP im trying to connect to. and i dont know why

Users and IPs censored for now. If I connect with heidisql (programm like navicat) everything works fine. Only my installed local apache 2.4 (php 5.5) can't connect to it

Traceroute looks like this:

```
  1     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  (censored)
  2    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.130.250
  3     2 ms     1 ms     1 ms  (censored)
  4   202 ms     6 ms   205 ms  (censored)
  5     5 ms     4 ms     4 ms  (censored)
  6     5 ms     5 ms     5 ms  (censored)
  7     *        *        *     Zeitüberschreitung der Anforderung.
  8    19 ms    18 ms    18 ms  rbx-g1-a9.fr.eu [94.23.122.76]
  9    19 ms    19 ms    19 ms  vac1-0-a9.fr.eu [178.33.100.149]
 10    21 ms    32 ms    28 ms  vac1-1-n7.fr.eu.firewall [178.33.100.152]
 11    20 ms    21 ms    18 ms  vac1-2-n7.fr.eu.tilera [37.187.36.245]
 12    19 ms    18 ms    18 ms  vac1-3-n7.fr.eu [91.121.215.13]
 13     *        *        *     Zeitüberschreitung der Anforderung.
 14    18 ms    18 ms    18 ms  5.39.6*.**
```

Code:

```
    $this->_mysqli = new \MySQLi($this->host, $this->username, $this->password, $this->db, $this->port);
```

host: target ip (5.39.6*.**)
user & pw: obviously private here
db: database name, exists for sure on the server
port: 3306

Error:

```
Access denied for user '*****'@'62.214.6*.***' (using password: YES)
```

Comment: You should start by providing the code that you are running and the desired outcome

Comment: Theres not much code i can provide beside the failed mysqli line, obviously i cant copy my whole code in here (about 10k lines). It worked flawless until now, don't know why i get this error now

Comment: The only thing I can add to that is what may seem obvious already. Your error is indicating access denied for the user, maybe check that you have set the correct username/pw ahead of your mysqli line? Its tough to know just from the above info

Comment: My problem is not the denied user. I connect to an ip 5.[...] and it says me access denied on an 62.[...] ip, i cant understand why it wants to connect to this 62.[...] ip

Comment: Thanks, messed up with connecting ip and ip to connect to... kinda awkward -.-' :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mysql permissions work in "triplets"
You have a "user", you have a "password" and also you have an "origin".

The user and password are pretty obvious in this case, the origin represents the ip who initiates the connection to the mysql server, in your case 62.214.6x.xxx like your traceroute indicates represents the public ip of your internet connection.

You have to check the permissions on your server to match this triplet, to do that execute

```
select * from information_schema.user_privileges 
  where GRANTEE like '%YOUR_USER%' group by grantee;
```

You will see something like

```
+-------------------------------------+---------------+----------------+--------------+
| GRANTEE                             | TABLE_CATALOG | PRIVILEGE_TYPE | IS_GRANTABLE |
+-------------------------------------+---------------+----------------+--------------+
| 'YOUR_USER'@'127.0.0.1'             | def           | SELECT         | YES          |
| 'YOUR_USER'@'62.214.8.8'            | def           | SELECT         | YES          |
```

Now you want to include the user '*****'@'62.214.6*.***' to these grants. You can use the GRANT command

```
grant all privileges on YOUR_BASE.* to '*****'@'62.214.6*.***'
  identified by password 'YOUR_PASSWORD';
```

If your ip is a dynamic one probably you will have to give permissions every time your ip changes or use a wildcard to cover a range of addresses '62.214.%' as example

heidisql has several ways to connect and probably its using a ssh tunnel so you dont have problems with that.